# Where does evince store its per-document state (position, etc)?

Tags: evince

I'm using evince to view my documents under Linux. One thing bothers me, however. It seems to magically remember the position and settings of the window *for every document*. I searched all over (the hidden directories in my home folder, system files, gconf) for where it might be saving those settings, but I can't find anything. Does anyone know where those settings are?

Answer (score 11):

The settings are *stored* under `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/`, but this knowledge is of little use since you cannot do anything practical with the binary files therein.

To read or edit the per-document settings, use the following gvfs tools, passing them the path to the document of which you want the settings:

- Reading: `gvfs-info /path/to/file`. Example line of output:
  `metadata::evince::n-copies: 5`
- Editing: `gvfs-set-attribute /path/to/file metadata::evince::n-copies 1`
- Removing: `gvfs-set-attribute /path/to/file -t unset metadata::evince::n-copies` (credits to Christophe Drevet-Droguet for this one!)

Paths can be relative to the current dir.

Comment: To reset all evince settings for a document: see http://askubuntu.com/a/819597/88086

Comment: @ChristopheDrevet-Droguet Thanks! Answer edited.

Comment: This answer should be updated as `gvfs-*` tools were deprecated in 2016 in favor of `gio`.

Comment: @vmonteco Thanks, I've submitted an edit.

Answer (score 8):

Things have changed since the previous answer was given (October 2011). The window settings of Evince are now being stored in binary, in the directory `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/`.

Comment: These seem to be binary files. Any way of figuring out what the settings actually are?

Comment: @Faheem, see the new answer that was just posted.

Answer (score 4):

The per document settings are stored in the file `~/.gnome2/evince/ev-metadata.xml`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [gio](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio.html) command. For example, to see the saved position for example.pdf, run `gio info -a "metadata::evince::page" example.pdf`.